# Android multidex exception.App works smoothly on API>21 but crashes below 21

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-multidex

The App works fine on API>=21 but crashes on lower API versions.I doubt its about Multidex.The Exception thrown is "Inflate Exception:Use Theme.AppCompat" ,where as i have already been using AppCompat library.I have tried everything and failed.Need some help.

[Gradle File(part-1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29Hix.png)

[Manifest File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4htPI.png)

Comment: can you please send the full crash log here?

Comment: i have added the image below.Can  You please guide me next?